# Get value from listbox and copy to control source of unbound textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a listbox, I want to get the value onclick and copy it to the control source of a listbox in microsoft access.

`SearchResults` is the name of the listbox

`BookTitle` is the name of the textbox

I have tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Private Sub SearchResults_OnClick()

BookTitle.ControlSource = Forms!Edit!SearchResults.Column(2)

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you wish to copy to the control source? Is it the name of a field? If not, just set the value:

```
Private Sub SearchResults_OnClick()

    Me.BookTitle = Me.SearchResults.Column(2)

End Sub
```

Do not forget that columns are numbered from zero.

Edit re comments

Very roughly.

Listbox:

```
SELECT ID, Title FROM tbl_Books WHERE Title LIKE ...
```

A little code:

```
Private Sub SearchResults_OnClick()
    'Save
    Me.Dirty=False
    'Find
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.SearchResults
End Sub
```

Add suitable control sources to any textboxes so you can edit the data in the underlying table. You can hide the textboxes if you wish.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes you are right your code works, but what I am actually trying to do is that when I click on an item from the list box the textbox will update with the BookTitle value so that I can edit and save the record

Comment: I think you are going the wrong way about this. What is the record source of your form? Is it based on a table or query that includes book title?

Comment: The listbox row source is based on a query "SELECT tbl_Books.* FROM tbl_Books WHERE tbl_Books.BookTitle Like '**';" and the LIKE value gets inserted from a word search box to filter the listbox results, I would then like some way of choosing and editing a listbox item and then saving that edit back in to the database! if you can help i would really appreciate it thank you for your time

Comment: Okay, in that case what you need to do is set up your listbox to include a unique id and use that id to navigate to the relevant record for the title in the click event.